# I don't understand Windows IRQL

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553079(v=vs.85).aspx

MSDN says `KeRaiseIrql(newIrql, &oldIrql)` must be called with `newIrql` which is >= `currentIrql`.

> "If the new IRQL is less than the current IRQL, a bug check
>   occurs."

But in below code `KeRaiseIrql()` works well with `newIrql` which is < `currentIrql`. (Also, both loading and unloading this driver worked well.)

Is there anyone to explain this?

Test Environment: WinXp(32bit, Vmware Player), Win7(32bit, Vmware Player)

```
#include <ntddk.h>

VOID DriverUnload
(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject
)
{
    DbgPrint("BYE!\n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry
(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
    IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
)
{
    KIRQL oldIrql;

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    DbgPrint("Hello!\n");

    KeRaiseIrql(3, &oldIrql);

    DbgPrint("%d\n", KeGetCurrentIrql()); // 3

    KeRaiseIrqlToDpcLevel();

    DbgPrint("%d\n", KeGetCurrentIrql()); // 2

    KeRaiseIrql(1, &oldIrql);

    DbgPrint("%d\n", KeGetCurrentIrql()); // 1

    KeRaiseIrql(0, &oldIrql);

    DbgPrint("%d\n", KeGetCurrentIrql()); // 0

    DbgPrint("Yo!\n");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are you building the driver in Debug mode or in Release mode?

Comment: @pepper_chico in debug mode.

Comment: In `wdm.h` header there's a version of `KeRaiseIrql` for x64 platforms for which there's a definition. It just uses `NT_ASSERT` for checking `newIrql > oldIrql`. [`NT_ASSERT` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff961903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implies it should bugcheck only in debug mode. Not sure whether the 32 bit version contains this assertion.

Comment: besides this, it just seems to write some register through `WriteCR8`, both for lowering as for raising.

Comment: Anyway, your curiosity seems unecessary. Why wonder about this? You better follow the docs than the contrary. Just use IRQ levels as expected by the system.

Comment: I just want to know why KeRaiseIrql is worked differently as expected. and still don't know why. Is this curiosity unnecessary?

Comment: IMO, it's not important. It's an implementation detail that's not reproducing... there's a lot of this. Technically you may not even discover why, if the hal lib is closed source, and this is to be reproduced through an assertion that's missing, you can't know.

Comment: You better ask this in OSR forums than here. Windows Drivers are rarely discussed in stackoverflow.

Comment: Anyway, knowledge of this won't make a difference about the way you _should_ develop drivers.

Answer (score 1):

As someone above suggested it depends on the given OS implementation. 
If you have issues like this, the best is to use debugger.

E.g. in win xp sp2 release i386 I have:

```
    hal!KfRaiseIrql:
    806e43b8 0fb6d1          movzx   edx,cl
    806e43bb 0fb68a98436e80  movzx   ecx,byte ptr hal!HalpIRQLtoTPR (806e4398)[edx]
    806e43c2 a18000feff      mov     eax,dword ptr ds:[FFFE0080h]
    806e43c7 890d8000feff    mov     dword ptr ds:[0FFFE0080h],ecx
    806e43cd c1e804          shr     eax,4
    806e43d0 0fb68018f26e80  movzx   eax,byte ptr hal!HalpVectorToIRQL (806ef218)[eax]
    806e43d7 c3              ret
```

As you can see there's no previous irql checking. If you'd look into wrk sources you would find versions of KfRaiseIrql where it is checked, also keep in mind there is checked and free windows version. Most probabbly in checked version you would have bugcheck.

If you want to see bsod on your code, use Driver Verifier :) afair it is checking if raising/lowering irql are used correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will try to use verifier and test more.

Comment: Bugcheck occurred using driver verifier. Although IRQL rule seems not to be strict sometimes, I think that complying this rule is important to avoid potential bugs.